# Wordpress Post Thumbnail metabox not appearing

Tags: thumbnails

WordPress version : 3.1
post thumbnail field not appearing in editor section except for Page editor .
My Code inside function.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); // Add it for posts

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'slider' ) ); //For Slider Image 

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'portfolio' ) ); //For Portfolio 

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'book' ) ); //For Book 

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) ); // Add it for pages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it,

```
1. add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

`2. set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );`

```
3. add_image_size( 'portfolio', 275, 152 );
```

First function adds the support.

Second changes the size of the thumbnail, there is resize mode like above or hard crop like this,

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true);
```

Which will not resize just crop.

Thirdly is a custom size set for a certain tag of posts, so for the portfolio tag the thumbnail would be 272, 152, box resize mode.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to add_theme_support for 'post-thumbnails' replaces the previous settings. You need to use

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'slider', 'portfolio', 'book') );
```

Personally - IMHO when you create your custom post types - adding the "post-thumbnails" to the support argument when you register the post_type.